# Потребление ресурсов web и python приложением

Tags: javascript, python, оптимизация, веб-программирование, сравнение

Есть написанная web-страница (HTML/CSS+JS), на которой расположен слайдер (сам переключается раз в минуту, фото около 100) и часы.
При переключении изображением на одноплатном слабом компьютере ЦП загружается на 100%, сек так на 10-20 и в это момент даже часы ужасно глючат, пропускают по 2-4сек. (сделаны через setInterval и получение через new Date()).
Веб страница расположена на памяти компьютера ,как и фото.
На ПК стоит Debian и chromium.

Вопрос заключается в том, что если сделать тоже самое, но только как приложение на python, будет ли оно лучше работать и меньше потреблять ресурсов ПК, если да, то на сколько и из-за чего.

---

код слайдера и часов:

**HTML**

```
<div class="image-main-div">
    <div id="prev_img"></div>
    <img class="image-main">
    <div id="next_img"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="time">00:00:00</div>
```

**JS**

```
/* Фото */
var path = '../photos/';
var loader = document.createElement('img');
setInterval(function(){
    nexImg();
},60000);
function nexImg(){
    var src = getNextImgSrc();
    loader.src = src;
    $('#voice p').text('load');
    loader.onload = function() {
        $('#voice p').text('finish');
        $('.image-main').attr('src', src);
    }
}
function getNextImgSrc(){
    /*if(i>103) i = 1;
    return path+(i++)+'.JPG';*/
    var id_img = randomInteger(1,103);
    if(history_img.length > 10) history_img.splice(2,1);
    history_img[history_img.length] = path+id_img+'.jpg';
    history_img_pointer = history_img.length;
    return path+id_img+'.jpg';
}

function randomInteger(min, max) {
    var rand = min + Math.random() * (max - min)
    rand = Math.round(rand);
    return rand;
}

/* Часы */
    var time_div = document.getElementById('time');
    setInterval(function(){
        var today = new Date();
        time_div.innerText = zeroPad(today.getHours())+':'+zeroPad(today.getMinutes())+':'+zeroPad(today.getSeconds());
    },1000);
```

Comment: На 99% зависит от кривизны рук пишущего код.

Comment: @andreymal, если всё сделать правильно и качественно, где нагрузка будет меньше?

Comment: Как я понял, все это у Вас локально? То есть Chromium отображает страницу с этого же компьютера, а сама страница HTML + js. Верно?

Comment: Т.е. вы хотите эту часть, перенести на сервер с клиента?

Comment: @AndrewHobbit ,да html страница находится на том же ПК где и открывается Chromium.

Comment: @A1essandro А что тут вообще можно перенести на сервер? Я хочу сделать тоже самое но только не на html+js ,а на python

Comment: Надо смотреть код слайдера. И часов, если проблема видна по ним.

Comment: @D-side я выше уже писал что если учитывать что всё написано хорошо, то кто больше будет потреблять? А вообще, слайдер сделан просто через setTimeot, как выходит время он загружает в фоне картинку (создаётся document.createElement('img') и в нём загружается), потом ставит его в src видимого изображения. Часы просто через setTimeot получает время через new Date() и всё.

Comment: @Mr_Epic добавьте в вопрос код слайдера. Может, кто-то в нём найдёт серьёзную проблему и предположение полетит ко всем чертям. Но если предполагать, то да, на Python это можно сделать существенно более шустрым, т. к. меньше слоёв абстракции. Ну и стоит убедиться, что фотографии по размеру именно такие, какие рендерятся на экране. Одноплатники обычно слабенькие, им лучше видеочип лишний раз не напрягать.

Comment: Мне кажется здесь слабое звено вообще Chromium. Поэтому если делать на питоне (не как веб-приложение), то работать будет лучше. Я бы для начала попробовал браузер другой использовать.

Comment: @AndrewHobbit какой например? Добавил код слайдера и часов.

Comment: Я половину рабочего времени с "недобуком" провожу, и знаю что такое тормоза. Особенно с Chrome и его сборками. Часто пользую легкие браузеры, чтобы быстро пошариться по интернету, там где не нужны мои закладки,пароли, синхронизации и прочие примочки. Мне нравится **dwb** браузер.